# Does Orochimaru know all his jutsu that he learned after he gave Anko the curse mark and was revived from it?

Tags: naruto

A portion of Orochimaru's consciousness was in Anko's curse mark, so he could see what she saw, but is this linked with his other consciousness? So that if the real Orochimaru thinks he learns a jutsu, does the Orochimaru in Anko learn it too? Is there any canon explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He didn't necessarily know all of the techniques the original had learnt.

But even if he didn't, the moment he absorbed his power back from Kabuto, he relearned everything (since the cells in Kabuto were from the time Sasuke "killed" him).

Comment: Why did orochimaru said, "who would have thought you would revive me Sasuke" soon after he was resurrected? His this conscience should not know Sasuke killed him?

Answer (score -3):

Orochimaru can go toe to toe with madara 
In the manga he can be killed now
Orochimaru can use all the past hokage 
And now that he has all kabuto's memory's 
He can use itachi Nagto and 3rd rikage
And all of the dead akasuki and he can
Also go in sage mode and
Orochimaru has sinjuu DNA he can use wood
Style look it up and now that he has sage 
Mode genjutsu cant work on him unless madara
Wants to lose a eye I'm sorry and for everyone 
That is saying he can just drop a comet well 
Than they both die now that madara's dum ass 
Made him self living again he would kill him self doing and now Orochimaru can use he's hand with out them he fucking punched the 4 tails 
In the face and that was with no jutsu so 
But Orochimaru wins

Comment: That does not answer the question. [anime.se] is not a forum. It's a question and answer site. Please don't try to start discussions in the answers. Please refer to the [help] and [about] to see what's this site all about.